Python printing diamond with question mark instead of characters ' " -
I'm scraping from a website and it prints out the characters ' " - as �.
It copies this:
“It’s only after we’ve lost everything that we’re free to do anything.” – Fight Club, Tyler Durden
But prints this:
�It�s only after we�ve lost everything that we�re free to do anything.� � Fight Club, Tyler Durden
Any ideas why this is happening?
I will be happy to attach code if needed
url:
https://everydaypower.com/famous-movie-quotes/
I dont know what to try and I couldn't find anything online about it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you're saving the quotes to file, specify explicitly the encoding as utf-8. If you print quotes to terminal, make sure the terminal supports unicode characters. E.g.:
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://everydaypower.com/famous-movie-quotes/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

quotes = []
for p in soup.select("#article-columns p"):
    q = p.text.strip()
    if re.match(r"\d+\.", q):
        quotes.append(q)

with open("out.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f_out:  # <-- specify the encoding
    print(*quotes, sep="\n", file=f_out)

This saves out.txt:
...

376. “There’s nothing wrong with me, I mean, I don’t like boys.” — Clyde Barrows.
377. “Why? What do you mean, ‘Why?’ Because you’re different, that’s why. You know, you’re like me. You want different things. You got somethin’ better than bein’ a waitress.” — Clyde Barrow.
378.. “Shoot, if we’d done half that stuff they said we’d done in that paper, we’d be millionaires by now, wouldn’t we?” — Clyde Barrows.
379. “You’re just like your brother. Ignorant, uneducated hillbilly, except the only special thing about you is your peculiar ideas about love-making, which is no love-making at all.” — Bonnie Parker.
380. “I don’t think he’s lost. I think the bank’s been offerin’ extra reward money for us. I think Frank just figured on some easy pickins, didn’t ya, Frank? — Clyde Barrow.
381. “Feast your eyes! Glut your soul on my accursed ugliness!” ― The Phantom of the Opera (1925)
382. “Wait a minute! Wait a minute! You ain’t heard nothin’ yet. Wait a minute, I tell ya, you ain’t heard nothin’! Do you wanna hear ‘Toot, Toot, Tootsie!’?” ― The Jazz Singer (1927)

...

